# Не работает роутинг

Tags: laravel, .htaccess

После переноса на сервер с локалки Laravel, перестали работать все ссылки.
www.test.ru/login не работает
Главная корректно отображается
.htaccess в public

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    <IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
        Options -MultiViews -Indexes
    </IfModule>

    RewriteEngine On

    # Handle Authorization Header
    RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
    RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]

    # Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (.+)/$
    RewriteRule ^ %1 [L,R=301]

    # Handle Front Controller...
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

Подскажите куда копать проблему ?

Answer (score 1):

Решение найдено

Если не работает роутинг:
    /etc/apache2/apache2.conf секция /var/www
    Заменить на AllowOverride All
    sudo service apache2 restart
    sudo a2enmod rewrite